# Is there a way to enforce parameterless constructor without generic constraint

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface, abstract-class

I have an interface `ISnack` which when implemented by a class, it should have a default parameterless constructor. Basically this:

```
public interface ISnack<T> where T : new()
{

}
```

I use `<T> where T : new()` just to enforce the parameterless constructor.

I would then implement the interface this way:

```
public class Cutlet : ISnack<Cutlet>
{

}
```

This works and it simply ensures `Cutlet` class has a parameterless constructor.

Now I have an abstract base class `Kitchen`:

```
public abstract class Kitchen<T> where T : ISnack
{

}
```

The requirement is that `Kitchen` should have constraint where `T` should be an `ISnack`. **But this wont work because there exists no `ISnack`, but only `ISnack<T>`.**

If I tried this

```
public abstract class Kitchen<T> where T : ISnack<T>
{

}
```

it wouldn't compile (`'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'ISnack<T>'`) and also wouldn't make sense in my context.

If I could force `ISnack`s to have a parameterless constructor without constraining by a `T` type parameter, then `T` in `Kitchen<T>` could easily be an `ISnack`. How to go about it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't unless you add the constraint; generic constraints are cumulative, so to make the compiler happy you would have to have:

```
public abstract class Kitchen<T> where T : ISnack<T>, new()
```

If that is fine, ***then do that***. If it isn't fine, then you'll have to remove the `: new` from the original, and make do without it. This isn't as bad as it sounds, but it means you push validation down to execution rather than compilation. But: `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()` still does what you would need, anyway - even without the `new()` constraint. So you can replace:

```
T newObj = new T(); // validated by the compiler
```

with:

```
T newObj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>(); // not validated until executed
```

A handy trick when removing constraints can be: add a unit/integration test that finds the candidate types via reflection, and validate the missing constraint *as part of your test suite*.

Comment: Marc, Ditto! you have outlined all that I have tried.. Hmmm runtime is the option I have I guess

Comment: @nawfal If it's ok, you can add a second generic argument to kitchen and this should work: `abstact class Kitchen<T, S> where T : ISnack<S> where S : new()`

Comment: @FelixK. can you make it another answer?

Comment: +1 for the handy trick about unit testing. [Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/benmccallum/df6db989badcda72e74ddeb7c9e5179c) for anyone that finds it useful to have an xunit theory using inline data to cover multiple assemblies and base types to validate a parameterless ctor exists on all concretions of those base type/s.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a second generic parameter:

```
abstact class Kitchen<T, S> 
    where T : ISnack<S> 
    where S : new()
....
```

This will solve your issue.

Adding a second parameter to a class also can cause some issues which i've faced since .NET 2.0 is available. Some complex situations may require to add more generic parameters to classes than you like to. Normally i break down the generic chain by adding more direct casts ( like `(SpecificType)base.MyTypeTProperty` ). *Comment: I try to find a sample later*

Comment: this works too, but I suppose is less elegant than the one Marc suggested

Comment: @nawfal Of course, and it can cause problems in more complex situations. I maybe gonna post a example later.

Answer (score 1):

simply add the constraint to T again

```
public abstract class Kitchen<T> where T : ISnack<T>, new()   {      }
```